# Unir 2 consultar agrupadas..!

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola necesito mostrar los datos de 2 consultas agrupadas, pero no me permite con **union all** , las 2 consultas  tienen un group by diferente

```
SELECT f.nombre as nombrefun, count( os.orden_id ) AS ordenes, sum(importe) as total
    FROM ordenes_servicio os
            INNER JOIN funerarias f ON os.funeraria_id = f.funeraria_id
    WHERE os.tipo_orden_id = 'S' AND os.anio = 2021
        GROUP BY os.funeraria_id ORDER BY nombrefun
UNION ALL
SELECT os.nombre_funeraria as nombrefun, count( os.orden_id ) AS ordenes, 
                                                    sum(importe) as total
    FROM ordenes_servicio os
        WHERE os.tipo_orden_id = 'R' AND os.anio = 2021
        GROUP BY nombrefun ORDER BY nombrefun
```

**pero solo obtengo un error**

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL
SELECT os.nombre_funeraria as nombrefun, count( os.orden_id ) AS o...' at line 6

> Cita en bloque

Comment: Los group by estan al reves????

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes con el `ORDER BY`, prueba a quitarlo

Comment: Tal y como dice @DavidJP el problema se resuelve al quitar el primer  `ORDER BY nombrefun` aunque otra solucion podría ser poner entre parentesis (...) desde el principio de la query hasta justo antes del UNION ALL

Answer (score 1):

Al final quedo asi..!

se dejaron los group by y solo un order by al final

```
SELECT f.nombre as nombrefun, count( os.orden_id ) AS ordenes, sum(importe) as total
    FROM ordenes_servicio os
            INNER JOIN funerarias f ON os.funeraria_id = f.funeraria_id
    WHERE os.tipo_orden_id = 'S' AND os.anio = 2021
        GROUP BY nombrefun
UNION ALL
SELECT os.nombre_funeraria as nombrefun, count( os.orden_id ) AS ordenes, 
                                                    sum(importe) as total
    FROM ordenes_servicio os
        WHERE os.tipo_orden_id = 'R' AND os.anio = 2021
        GROUP BY nombrefun 
ORDER BY nombrefun
```